# How to add backslash into json string as my web api request?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this Javascript code which get the form data and, convert the data input into object and then stringify it to send a web api request. How to add backslash into json string as my web api request?

Example from

```
{"application_name":"test1","application_name_Id":"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd0"}
```

to

```
{\"application_name\":\"test1\",\"application_name_Id\":\"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd0\"}
```

---

```
function PostForm() {
        const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
      
        const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form).entries());
        
        const obj = Object.fromEntries(data); 
        
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (!isNaN(obj[key])) {
                obj[key] = Number(obj[key]);
            }
        }

        const stringifyObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log(stringifyObj)

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:7273/WeatherForecast',
            type: 'POST',
            data: stringifyObj,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
            }
        });
    }
```

In my web api, I am using C#. So this is the code. It works as well. I can see the value in `jsonString`. But when I change the type from `dynamic` to `string`, it doesn't work because  the value in `jsonString` is

```
"{"application_name":"test1","application_name_Id":"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd0"}"
```

and not

```
"{\"application_name\":\"test1\",\"application_name_Id\":\"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd0\"}"
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] dynamic jsonString)
{
   // code removed as brevity.
}
```

The code works fine.

If I change to `data:obj`, I will get this error message

```
{type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…}
errors
: 
{$: ["'a' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],…}
status
: 
400
title
: 
"One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId
: 
"00-b01059fa2d870ff1f3e4309f6291cc9e-d02e73b547a874f5-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

and this is the payload request.

[image]

There is no backslash in `jsonstring`
[image]

Unable to deserialize a dynamic type.
[image]

Comment: I don't know why you need this, but just `JSON.stringify` the string.

Comment: why you need this? Are you facing any issue because `\` not present? What issue you are facing?

Comment: @mplungjan, if I send the `obj`, i get this error message `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-a6e726e2563c7143a8aaee3854b920ea-6208cd129168683f-00","errors":{"$":["'a' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"jsonString":["The jsonString field is required."]}}`

Comment: @Teemu and @Chetan, I need the backslash in the jsonstring so that I can deserialize it.  `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`

Comment: I can convert `jsonString` to `string` using this code `string jsonString2 = Convert.ToString(jsonString);` but after deserialize, I got a double curly braces for the object

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no concrete class that I can define in the C# method parameter. Thus, I am using dynamic type. so I need to pass it in as a string type.

Comment: @Teemu, I have tried to set `data: obj`,  but i get this error message `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-a6e726e2563c7143a8aaee3854b920ea-6208cd129168683f-00","errors":{"$":["'a' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"jsonString":["The jsonString field is required."]}}`

Comment: Open Network tab on DevTools, and check what really is posted.

Comment: Yep, I've read your post a bit poorly. Stringify the object and set `processData: false` in the `ajax` settings object, forging the content type as shingo has suggested is not a good idea.

Comment: @Teemu, but I still can't define my jsonString in C# as string.

Comment: I don't quite get it, the data you post is now a (valid JSON) string, you just need to deserialize it, don't try to convert it to anything before deserializing. Wait! Now after you've added a screenshot, it looks like `jsonString` is deserialized automatically by your server before you're getting the value from body.

Comment: @Teemu, can't directly deserialize a dynamic type. It will break. I have updated my post with the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you tell the server that the data you sent is a json string, the server will then deserialize the string to an object and pass it to the handler.

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

If you REALLY want to receive a string from the client, change the content type to:

```
contentType: "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
```

If you cannot change the content type you can also stringify the string again:

```
const stringifyObj = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: When I tried that and in my C# I changed to `string` instead of `dynamic`, I got this error message. `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-14a75728648c1110aef1d034c625f6ff-cc699d25855c1021-00"}`

Comment: Which one you tried? Plain text is not a bulit-in format in asp.net core, you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to add one.

Comment: Thanks. Finally got this solved using this approach from you. This is the resource I found, https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2020/02/29/asp-net-core-how-to-make-a-controller-endpoint-that-accepts-text-plain/